# How do I style a material-ui Icon which was passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm writing a custom Material UI React component which I want to pass an `Icon` into as a prop. However I want to style the icon when I get it and make it a minimum width and height.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I want to apply the `iconStyle` to the icon passed in as `props.statusImage` but can't figure out how.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconStyle: {
    minWidth: 100,
    minHeight: 100
  }
});

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return <div>{props.statusImage}</div>;
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyComponentWithIconProps;
```

I use the component like this

```
import {Done} from "@material-ui/icons";
<MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={<Done/>}
```

Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-fermi-dmb0p

I've also tried wrapping the supplied `Icon` in another `Icon` element and  attempting to style that. However that didn't work and seems sort of 'hacky' anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are three main alternatives:

1. Pass in the element type of the icon rather than an element (e.g. `Done` instead of `<Done/>`) and then add the `className` as you render the element (this is the approach in Fraction's answer).
2. Clone the element in order to add the `className` prop to it.
3. Put a class on the parent element and target the appropriate child type (e.g. `svg`).

Approach 1:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Done } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MyComponentWithIconProps from "./MyComponentWithIconProps";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={Done} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**MyComponentWithIconProps.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconStyle: {
    minWidth: 100,
    minHeight: 100
  }
});

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const StatusImage = props.statusImage;
  return (
    <div>
      <StatusImage className={styles.iconStyle} />
    </div>
  );
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyComponentWithIconProps;
```

[image: Edit add class to icon prop]

---

Approach 2:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Done } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MyComponentWithIconProps from "./MyComponentWithIconProps";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={<Done />} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**MyComponentWithIconProps.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconStyle: {
    minWidth: 100,
    minHeight: 100
  }
});

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const styledImage = React.cloneElement(props.statusImage, {
    // Using clsx to combine the new class name with any existing ones that may already be on the element
    className: clsx(styles.iconStyle, props.statusImage.className)
  });
  return <div>{styledImage}</div>;
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyComponentWithIconProps;
```

[image: Edit add class to icon prop]

---

Approach 3:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Done } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MyComponentWithIconProps from "./MyComponentWithIconProps";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={<Done />} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**MyComponentWithIconProps.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconStyle: {
    "& > svg": {
      minWidth: 100,
      minHeight: 100
    }
  }
});

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return <div className={styles.iconStyle}>{props.statusImage}</div>;
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyComponentWithIconProps;
```

[image: Edit add class to icon prop]

Answer (score 3):

Pass the icon like this:

```
<MyComponentWithIconProps statusImage={Done} />
```

then use it as follows:

```
return <div><props.statusImage className={styles.iconStyle} /></div>;
```

Comment: No not yet. I will try now.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the following error - ```Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:285953:38```

Comment: check this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-moser-8why8

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can style the icon prop directly with `sx`:

`<EleIcon sx={{ height: '2.5vh', width: '2.5vw' }} />`

`EleIcon` is the icon passed to my component

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  iconStyle: {
    minWidth: 100,
    minHeight: 100,
    color: "red"
  }
});

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();

  return <div className={styles.iconStyle}>{props.statusImage}</div>;
}

MyComponentWithIconProps.propTypes = {
  statusImage: PropTypes.element
};

export default MyComponentWithIconProps;
```

Comment: This doesn't style the Icon though, it only styles the div. So the div gets bigger but not the Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Worked for me perfectly

Component

```
import MyLocationIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MyLocation';

<TextInputComp Icon={MyLocationIcon} />
```

Component code

```
function TextInputComp(p: any) {
    const {Icon } = p;
    return (
        <Icon fontSize={'large'} />
    )
}
```