# Why do I get an Invariant Violation when I don't include an optional prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This relates to a previous question which I posed here([How do I style a material-ui Icon which was passed as prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878858/how-do-i-style-a-material-ui-icon-which-was-passed-as-prop)). My original problem is solved (i.e. Passing an Icon element as a prop and styling it in the receiving component).

However I want that prop to be optional. When I don't pass it I get an **Invariant Violation** which I cannot figure out. I've tried numerous options to handle a 'undefined' prop but to no avail.

See here for the issue.

[image: Edit add class to icon prop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not rendering your div correctly, it must be rendered by a function

```
const Div = () => <div />;

function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const StatusImage = props.statusImage ? props.statusImage : Div;
  return (
    <div>
      <StatusImage className={styles.iconStyle} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/add-class-to-icon-prop-nmpw8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Ah I see. So basically returning it from a function "wraps" it as a variable. Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if your `StatusImage` was already set to `<div/>`, then you invoked it again like this `<StatusImage />`, that doesn't make a lot of sense does it?

Do this instead:

```
function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const statusImage = props.statusImage ? <props.statusImage className={styles.iconStyle}/> : <div />;
  return (
    <div>
      {statusImage}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah yes I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value to `StatusImage`:

```
function MyComponentWithIconProps(props) {
  const styles = useStyles();

  const { statusImage: StatusImage = 'div' } = props;
  // OR
  // const MyDiv = (props) => <div {...props} />
  // const { statusImage: StatusImage = MyDiv } = props;

  return (
      <div>
        <StatusImage className={styles.iconStyle} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit add class to icon prop]